# .editorconfig to indent c# top level statements

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, editorconfig, asp.net-core-6.0

We just created a new project using asp.net 6 template and we just balked in disgust. Program.cs looks like a 1990's chunk of C code and is godawful and ugly and glued to the left edge, and, well, just yuck. I know we can dispose of that all and make the old program/startup layout, but seeing how asp.net crew tends to breaks things from version to version, we decided we'll accept their new normative (ugh), but we would at least like to indent the code in top-level statements 4 spaces. Yet, we can't seem to find anything that relates to that in .editoconfig settings.

Any idea how we can achieve this or is refactoring back to asp.net core 5 namespace/class "layout" the only escape?

Comment: I don't believe there's any support for indenting top-level code, such as classes, namespaces, and top-level statements. Just tick `public class Program { public static void Main() {` before the top-level statements generated by the template, and `} }` after it

Comment: Can you not just put it all in a `{ }` ? It's legal C# to have a scoped block with nothing heading the block https://dotnetfiddle.net/I3zhQc

Comment: "we decided we'll accept their new normative" - but not really. I'm confused about the aim here. I think you might be missing [the point of this feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements) and I don't think you should be afraid of the classical `Main` method being deprecated. So why not stick to the old ways if you find top-level statements so awful?

Comment: Top level statements only really affect program.cs. Is this really a big problem fory you? What's your use case?

Comment: @tymtam, do I need a use case, its just ugly visually and looks unstructured. And in a beautiful structured language, its just blasphemy. if you do not see a problem with it, kudos to you. We do.

Comment: @Xerillio but we do, not accepting would mean refactoring back to program/startup. We understand the point, and see its appeal in prototyping, but making it the main driver for complex projects? Ugh, just ugh, gross. What happens when some junior plants a line of top-level code in a project of thousand source files? Turning C# into inline script language is nonsense.

Comment: @CaiusJard it seems this is the best solution we can hope for. If you make this into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of focusing on the left side observe that you're gaining 4 or 8 spaces on the right. You solution explorer - or and any other window - can get bigger now!

*Optionally, for the bold: Why not even try turning your monitor 90 degrees and see more code vertically. Mmm..lovely.*

#### Moving things around

You could move your your widgets around to counteract the too-much-to-the-left effect.

[image]
vs

[image]

#### Indicator and selection margins

These are on by default and most likely you have them on but it's worth pointing out you can move text left/right with selection and indicator margins

With both off:

[image]

With both on:

[image]

[image]

Comment: we all have 21:9 screens, we do not need more space on the right. We need structure, in a structured language. Go figure.

Comment: Oh, and you forgot, because program.cs is now an unstructured "script", every code line literally begins with "builder." so you actually lose additional 4 characters on the right... Go figure that also.

Comment: *Why not even try turning your monitor 90 degrees* - kinda like in the old days when monitors were 4:3 and office productivity wasn't sacrificed on the altar of movie-based entertainment? :D (Posted from a Thinkpad T60p)

Comment: Re: 90: I was thinking more like your phone, tablet, books and cereal box